# Create a connector: Error while using some characters in setId

Tags: looker-studio

When I use some characters like `|, -` etc. in `setID()` this error happens before calling `getData()`

> Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your
>   request.

```
fields.newMetric()
.setId('xtras|avg_days')
.setName('avg_days')
.setType(types.NUMBER)
.setAggregation(aggregations.AVG)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only alphanumeric characters and underscores are allowed for Data Studio Community Connector field Ids.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#field (check under Legacy. In Legacy, `Id`s are called `name`s and `name`s are called `label`s).